# Very fast firing of events causes "undefined" error using as3commons-async framework

Tags: apache-flex, asynchronous, actionscript, air

I have implemented a simple sync routine using the as3commons-async framework (which I thought to be stable as a rock)

I have a CompositeCommand containing a high number of other commands, which can also be composite commands.

Now some strange thing happens:

When executed slowly (over the web) everything works as expected.

Now I leave out the part doing the heavy load causing the commands to run at "machine" speed.

After a couple of dozens, sometimes more than a hundred "progress" events fired, AIR player crashes with this error message:

```
undefined
at org.as3commons.async.operation.impl::AbstractProgressOperation/dispatchProgressEvent()[C:\projects\as3-commons\as3-commons-async\src\main\actionscript\org\as3commons\async\operation\impl\AbstractProgressOperation.as:135]
at org.as3commons.async.command.impl::CompositeCommand/onCommandResult()[C:\projects\as3-commons\as3-commons-async\src\main\actionscript\org\as3commons\async\command\impl\CompositeCommand.as:287]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at org.as3commons.async.operation.impl::AbstractOperation/dispatchCompleteEvent()[C:\projects\as3-commons\as3-commons-async\src\main\actionscript\org\as3commons\async\operation\impl\AbstractOperation.as:152]
```

looking at the AbstractProgressOperation code in the async lib at the given line, there's nothing really done there:

```
/**
     * Convenience method for dispatching a <code>OperationEvent.PROGRESS</code> event.
     * @return true if the event was dispatched; false if not
     */
    protected function dispatchProgressEvent():void {
        dispatchEvent(OperationEvent.createProgressEvent(this));
    }
```

I can rule out my code as the culprit as well, as all parts of it are working seperately and are tested in many other aspects. Plus I don't really do anything either right now other than calling execute() on the command and fire an complete event.

For debugging I added some heavy trace() calls, which assumingly causes a slight delay, and voilà, it now crashes some lines further down in the code, still with "undefined" pointing a line in the code which is very unsuspicious. (once it was a call to invalidateDisplayList() in a component used for several years now without ever having made any problems)

Did anybody else encounter problems before when a large set of events is fired in very short time? What else can cause this strange "undefined" ?

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work on this library but you can delay the event firing by using the magical setTimeout as following:

```
  protected function dispatchProgressEvent():void {
       setTimeout(function():void
           {
               dispatchEvent(OperationEvent.createProgressEvent(this));
           }, 0);
    }
```

This will delay the execution of the dispatchEvent until all current operations processed.

Comment: (at)Anas (sorry, doing the @ thing doesn't work for me?) Thanks for sharing this little trick. Unfortunately it doesn't change the behaviour of my code. It still crashes, now on the line calling the function defined in set timeout. I even tried to rise the delay up to 1000ms, still no effect. I'm getting suspicious the stacktrace might point at the wrong position and the crash happens a bit earlier?

Comment: mmm so it is look like not synchronization issue, can you share the whole project/code so i can have a look.

Comment: I will try to put up a test case project as Roland suggested as soon as possible. Unfortunately I'm quite busy today, so maybe tomorrow. Thank you both for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on the as3commons-async library. I don't have a definitive answer for you, I'm afraid, just my suspicion that this error isn't necessarily related to as3-async.

You describe similar weird happenings in other areas of the code base (even in Flex itself), so this kind of smells like either a Flex bug or maybe even a bug in the AIR runtime.

The only thing I can advice here is to create a test application that fires events in a similar fashion and speed (so, without using as3-async) to see whether you can re-create the errors.

If it does turn out to be a runtime issue, at least you'll have a solid testcase to send to Adobe.

I apologize for not being able to help you out concretely.

cheers,

Roland